# Android Layouts? Whats the best way to do this grids?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to create a Tiled Layout with fixed ImageViews. The tiled layout should look like this :
Orientation of device horizontal which should be considered as 10x20(LxB).
I want to partition it in 5 vertical panels which will contain 20 images of same image in each panel. One image is considered as 1x2(LxB). I want the layout to be fixed on the screen and NOT scrollable.

> So whats the best way to achieve this in Android.

Should I use GridView?
Should I use TableLayout?
what is the best way to do this accurately and efficiently. Keeping in mind that we cannot use Nested Weights in layouts if I try to use Fixed Focus Linear layouts with weights.

> 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555
>
> 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555
>
> 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555
>
> 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555
>
> 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555

I want fixed horizontal layout like this considering 1,2,3,4,5 as fixed images.

Answer (score 0):

Use GridView, that way you won't have to worry about different screen sizes and orientations

Comment: I want to view it in on a single device that is Samsung Galaxy Note